# How do I forbid playing games during working hours?

Tags: windows

I work from home and I want to make sure I don't slack off when I should be working.

On Windows, what's an easy way to stop a given program from being launched during given hours?

Valid solutions include options built into windows, .bat scripts and anything that doesn't require a lot of configuration.

Comment: What operating system will the worker be using?  Is the computer connected to a domain?

Comment: I have found a two by four the most effective method. . .

Comment: If there are serious consequences for gaming during work hours then it will stop.

Comment: Eh, it's for me. Not for a child, not for an employee, for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use parental controls.

You can use Parental Controls to determine which specific programs your child can use.

1. Open Parental Controls by clicking the **Start button** , clicking **Control Panel**, and then, under **User Accounts**, clicking **Set up Parental Controls**.‌   If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
2. Click the name of the person you want to prevent from using specific programs.
3. Under **Parental Controls**, click **On**.
4. Click **Block specific programs**.
5. Click **Person's name‌ can only use the programs I allow in this list**.
6. Select the programs that you want to allow. If the program you want doesn't appear in the list, click **Browse** to locate the program.

Make sure that you select all of the programs that you want to be able to run. Parental Controls will block any program not selected in the list.

I would suggest using parental controls for a "**WORK**" user, and allowing anything to run on your normal or "**GAMES**" user.

Answer (score -1):

[RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) is a great utility. The only issue may be that it costs money.